# I cannot obtain the "AnimatedEmojie" stickersets through Pyrogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, pyramid, pyrogram

I cannot obtain the "AnimatedEmojie" stickersets through Pyrogram.
After testing, I can normally obtain other sticker sets.

Code:

```
sticker_set = await client_.invoke(
            GetStickerSet(stickerset=InputStickerSetShortName(short_name="AnimatedEmojies"), hash=0))
```

ErrorMessage:

```
Error: "Telegram says: [400 STICKERSET_INVALID] - The requested sticker set is invalid (caused by "messages.GetStickerSet")".
```

I want to know how I can obtain the https://t.me/addstickers/AnimatedEmojies sticker pack normally.